# Error ocurred while executing AddSErvicePrincipalPolicy in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, claims, azure-policy

I get the following error when executing the following command:

[image]

I need this because I have to assign the policy to my service entity

In Azure AD , in api permissions I have this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy: Error occurred while executing AddApplicationPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490177/15969115) and [Executing the New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment step returns a Forbidden error](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22700#issuecomment-480724589)